# MacBook Pro touchpad not clicking? (Hardware issue?)

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

My hands were a little wet when I touched the touchpad on my MacBook Pro 15". I think that a little water went into the cracks, or the tiny space around touchpad. The "click" mechanism stopped working properly. Multitouch still works perfectly.

I ordered a new touchpad, but NO! Problem remained. Touchpad still only registers "clicks" from bottom left corner.

I use my comp for work (Photoshop, Illustrator).

I tried loosening, tightening the screw on touchpad. Still nada.

Please help?

Edit: I need the physical "click." I use laptop for work. The touch to click does not function well with real work in Illustrator and Photoshop. I don't want to sound like a jerk, but please don't suggest the use of a mouse or "touch to click". These are not real answers to my question.

Comment: If loosening the small screw didn't work, then I suggest you have Apple verify that it was installed correctly and works, or replace the trackpad again.

Answer (score 6):

Check your MacBook's battery. My trackpad stopped clicking consistently, and then sometimes locked in click-down, keeping me from de-selecting things. When I opened it up I noticed that the battery was puffed up a bit. If I removed the battery and closed the case, the trackpad clicked just fine. Apple replaced the battery and all's good.

Answer (score 6):

Try pushing down relatively firmly on the trackpad but not so hard to break the glass or damage the delicate springs. By pressing on all four corners, you can sometimes dislodge a piece of crumb on a pad that moves physically.

Without opening the computer, I’m 100% sure if it fixed the problem for me (MacBook Pro 15" Mid 2014) by pushing the battery back into place so that the trackpad can move down more when clicking it or if it was debris. I suppose if it’s battery swelling, that will just get worse again but then I’ll know.

Source: the comments in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IuYO0I-DY84).

**EDIT** I was thinking this could be caused by picking up the MacBook (with the screen folded open) with one hand on one corner next to the trackpad, as I do now and then. I can imagine this pushing up the battery a little bit or slowly undo or break the plastic fasteners.

Comment: It might be broken. Take it into your local Apple Store and be truthful: you got water in the clicker. In the meantime, have you tried using a Magic Trackpad?

Comment: Pushing down on all four corners worked for me!

Comment: +100000000 pressing down on all four corners worked for me too!!

Comment: I would recommend looking at iFixit to see the size of the springs and the screws that hold the glass trackpad in place. Relatively hard might mean different things for different people. My experience is if you end up with divots in the flesh of your fingers for more than 5 seconds if you press and hold for 10 - you're pressing a little too hard. Also, if the battery is swelling or moving, that's a sign that it needs to be replaced due to off gassing into the pouch that keeps the chemistry sealed. Best to not re-compress a swelling battery.

Comment: After nearly a year, both the trackpad and the battery are still working fine. The [battery capacity](http://ccbonline.coconut-flavour.com/index.php?bid=cb013781a047b16528663556d0d2b83b) follows the average for MacBook batteries. I haven't needed pressing down on the trackpad again for as long as I can remember either. So I'd dare say nothing's broken.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I checked the battery, and it's also puffed up! I took it out and this solved all the trackpad issues I had.  ow, hopefully Apple will be nice about replacing the battery!

I had recently had a lot of issues with the computer overheating, which had mysteriously stopped just before the track pad stopped working. Somehow related to the puffed up battery, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If you really work in Photoshop or Illustrator, get the Wacom for god sake.
Regarding the touchpad it is a common issue. Mine seems better when I start working but required more and more firm clicks during the work. Going to disassemble the laptop, fix the battery position, and reassemble.

That happened after I spilled a cup of tea on it 2 days ago.

Answer (score -1):

Since you said that the multi-touch on the trackpad works, one work around is to enable the **Tap to click** setting in **System Preferences** > **Trackpad**:

[image]

This way you can tap your trackpad to click instead of having to rely on physically depressing it.

Comment: I need to use the physical click because I use Photoshop, Illustrator, etc. Single tap doesn't work too well when you need to drag and drop, manipulate objects.

Comment: Single tap is bad, but have you tried three-finger dragging? My trackpad DOES work, but three-finger drag is so convenient that I've almost stopped using the physical click...

Comment: This is a workaround but it helped